# Routing in Rails for better URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8.

Wondering, is there a way to re-route such url?

Old:

```
http://localhost:3000/shops/16-white-cafe-house?type=cafes
```

New:

```
http://localhost:3000/cafes/16-white-cafe-house
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of one way, via namespace:

In rails 3, I would do:

```
namespace 'cafe' do
  match '/:cafe_name(.:format)', :to => 'shop#show',
end
```

Which should generate urls like: http://localhost:3000/cafe/16-white-cafe-house

Perhaps you can dig up the Rails 2.3.8 guides for an equivalent code structure.

Hope that helps!